# Definition, dimension and opposite of web data

Tags: definition

I am writing a paper about how to make data related research more established in social science and provide a terminology of data types of at the moment 18 different data dimensions, which all consist of multiple classes. E.G. dimension name "Processing degree" is differing the data types "raw data" and "processed data". I have however one problem with the term: Web data.
My question to you experts is: How would you define Web Data and are there any types of data classes, which are Non-Web data? What term could you think of as the dimension name? I already have a dimension called accessibility, which is differing publicly available, restricted and closed data. Web data is somehow related to this dimension, but still different.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I found a definition on an application forum for Wandera (I use to monitor cell phone data)
https://wandera.force.com/Customer/s/article/202486889

It calls non-web data whatever flows through the hotspot feature of an LTE hotspot during it's use.

"The use of tethering (mobile hotspot creation) as well as a a subset of mobile apps use other ports which are not subject to the device proxy setting and therefore bypass the Wandera gateway. The Wandera app has been designed to capture these exceptions and classify them as Non-Web Data."